# Site's folders disappearing from Apache root folder

Tags: apache, root

Hope this message is at its place on this forum (if not tell me, I will switch it to another 'stackexchange')
I am installing a site in local, call it 'mysite', and I am still unable to run it correctly (I have an 500 error message when launching it). But it is weird is as follow : When I go to the root of my server, I put in the browser the url `localhost:8888/`. So it is displayed the list of all my local site, but 'mysite' doesn't appear. Strangely, when I try to find it from the console I find him. Could some one explain why it disappears from the root of my server (perhaps it will explain the 500 internal server error)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was simply an .htaccess file that I didn't first saw from the site I imported from github !!